# Past-the-last element for non default-constructible elements

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Working on a tree class with an STL-like interface, I encountered a problem using non default-constructible elements:

As I'm implementing iterators, I need a past-the-last element at any point in time. My approach is to create one in the constructor, which asserts the value type to be default constructible.

Is there an approach to get rid of this constraint?

Comment: Placement new can spare you premature construction... just saying

Comment: Past the end elements are not supposed to exist.

Comment: When you say past-the-last element, perhaps you mean a `end` element, which for raw arrays may be a pointer to one past the last element, but is not required to be. You can make some sentinel type to represent 'end' instead.

Comment: Not having a past-the-end element was my first approach. In terms of a pointer-based tree, this would naturally be a nullptr. The problem occurs the the moment I try to implement a bidirectional iterator. How am I supposed to find the last element from the past-the-last iterator?

Comment: The solution adopted by some STL implementation is to have a one-past-last *node* that doesn't contain any element. Tbis requires having two node types, usually derived from a comon base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing past the end can't possibly be `nullptr` if your iterator is bidirectional, `end()--` needs to be legal.

It can be instead implemented by a sentinel, and in this case, the sentinel shouldn't even contain a default constructed element.

This can be done as such

```
struct link
{
    link *parent, *left, *right;
};

template<typename T>
struct node : link
{
    T data;
};

template<typename T>
struct tree : link
{
    // tree itself serves as the sentinel
    // At initialization parent and childs should all point to the sentinel
    tree() : parent(this), left(this), right(this) {}

    // ...
};
```

And iterators need no special handling for one past the end case.

```
// nested within tree
struct iterator
{
    explicit iterator(link* l) : n(l) {}
    iterator& operator--() { n = n->parent; return *this; }  // or something else
    auto& operator*() { return reinterpret_cast<node<T>*>(n)->data; }

    // ...

    link* n;
};
iterator begin() { return {left}; } // or something else
iterator end() { return {this}; }
```

Comment: You can totally have the iterator type be `nullptr`. You just need to add a check in `operator--()`. Arguably that is better than leaking the node type into client code.

Comment: @nwp The node type isn't leaked, check `tree`'s interface. How do you go backwards from a `nullptr`? Say when you have 2 trees, how do you know which `end()` you are referring to? Note the iterator has only one pointer, there is not another pointing to the tree itself

Comment: That is the general solution I was looking for, @PasserBy!

Comment: You can't use a raw pointer for a tree anyways. You need something like `struct Iterator { Node *node; };` in order to be able to implement `operator--()` at all and `Iterator{nullptr};` works just fine as a past-end-iterator value. As far as I can see `tree` `public`ly inherits from `link` and `link` is also accessible which it shouldn't be.

Comment: @nwp `link` should of course be hidden in some implementation namespace, and why do I need more than a raw pointer? [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36cddd02cf70ef98)'s a toy implementation of a doubly linked list using the same idea above. It's slightly buggy due to not having `const_iterator` because I'm lazy

Comment: Because a raw pointer's operators `++` and `--` assume contiguous memory layout, which is not true for a tree. But I see we mean the same thing, you wrote `class iterator` too. I still don't like that `struct link` and `struct node` are accessible from client code though. They should also be a `private` type of `tree` just like `iterator` which makes inheriting from `link` an issue.

Comment: @nwp Oh, I thought you meant I need more than a pointer. But I'm confused. What about the stuff shown above not work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by storing another pointer to the root node, from which I can recreate the last element in constant time.